# Php pdo complex query with date

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, pdo

Here I have mysql database `'track_aktivnosti'`

[image]

Now I get from jquery ajax value of `id_akt`. Now I need to compare dates WHERE id_akt=22, so I need to get lowest date and get like this query:

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT naziv FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE datum=(lowest date) AND id_akt=:id_akt");
     $result->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt']));
     $result = $result->fetchAll(); 
.
.
.
after that again but with next date so like this:

$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT naziv FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE datum=(next lowest date) AND id_akt=:id_akt");
     $result->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt']));
    $result = $result->fetchAll();
```

so for me is the biggest problem how to find lowest date for some value of id_akt and from there get naziv, vrednost

Someone to have idea?

Comment: so first I need to get for some id_akt all dates and compare it, lowest is for first query, next is for second query ... ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with these two solutions. I don't know if these are good ideas. You can change it as you like.

First solution.

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT datum FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt GROUP BY datum ORDER BY datum");

$result->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt']));

$dates = $result->fetchAll();

$final_result = array();

foreach($dates as $date){

     $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT naziv, vrednost FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt AND datum = :datum");

     $result->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt'], ':datum' => $date['datum']));

     $final_result[$date['datum']] = $result->fetchAll();
}
```

Second solution

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT datum FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt GROUP BY datum");

$result->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt']));

$count = $result->rowCount();

$final_result = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ){

    $limit = $i.',1';

    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT datum FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt GROUP BY datum ORDER BY datum $limit");

    $result->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt']));

    $result = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $date = $result['datum'];

    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT naziv, vrednost FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt AND datum = :datum");

    $result->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt'], ':datum') => $result['datum']);

    $final_result[$date] = $result->fetchAll;

}
```

In both solutions, the results was stored in the `$final_result` array with dates as keys.

The results that I got from the first solution

```
array(1) { ["2013-04-01"]=> array(5) { [0]=> array(4) { ["naziv"]=> string(9) "nema nema" [0]=> string(9) "nema nema" ["vrednost"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(4) { ["naziv"]=> string(9) "nema nema" [0]=> string(9) "nema nema" ["vrednost"]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(1) "0" } [2]=> array(4) { ["naziv"]=> string(10) "Laza Lazic" [0]=> string(10) "Laza Lazic" ["vrednost"]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(1) "0" } [3]=> array(4) { ["naziv"]=> string(12) "John Deer n7" [0]=> string(12) "John Deer n7" ["vrednost"]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(1) "0" } [4]=> array(4) { ["naziv"]=> string(10) "Pera Peric" [0]=> string(10) "Pera Peric" ["vrednost"]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(1) "0" } } }
```

Comment: please fix it, I really need this

Comment: but i got the result when i `var_dump($final_result)`

Comment: i get just dates, but no data for each date ...look: array(3) { ["2013-04-01"]=> array(0) { } ["2013-09-08"]=> array(0) { } ["2014-06-25"]=> array(0) { } } $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT datum FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt GROUP BY datum ORDER BY datum"); $result->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt'])); $dates = $result->fetchAll(); $final_result = array(); foreach($dates as $date){ $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT naziv, vrednost FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt AND datum = :datum"); $result->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt'], ':datum' => ...etc

Comment: We must be missing something here. hmmph. I've recreated your sample table and i replaced the post with 22. I've updated my answer with the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT naziv, LOWER(datum) FROM track_aktivnosti
WHERE id_akt = id_akt
```

You need to query a lower datum

Comment: yes but some datum is in many places the same... I will try your query

Comment: If you have the same id with excatly the same date data in multiple registers, then you're going to get more than 1 result in the queue, but you can't do nothing more to get a lower between them, cause they are the same date.